# Is it possible to navigate to a file and a line number from within vim's own terminal?

Tags: vim

When I run a `make` command within the vim's own terminal and I get results with a file name and a number in there, is it possible to navigate to that location?

```
main.c:23:29: error: expected ';' after expression
```

In that case, I would like to go on the line above and from there, go to that buffer and line number.

Comment: By default, when you run 'make' vim will automatically navigate to the first error.  What have you changed that prevents that from happening?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I think they're running `make` in the `:terminal`.

Comment: You should use `:help :make` and `:help quickfix` instead of `$ make` in a `:terminal`. The quickfix is an awesome feature.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, the shell provided by the built-in `:terminal` can be used in two ways: as a "non-interactive" shell for running a single command, and as an "interactive" shell where you can run several commands consecutively.

If you are doing something like `:terminal make`, then you are in the first case and the command (`make`, here) is expected to "finish" at some point, printing eventual errors at the end.

In this context, the command is "finished" in `:terminal`, Vim goes back to terminal-normal mode, where all the usual normal mode commands apply. At this point, you should be able to do any of the following:

- press `gF` on the filename to edit the filename at the given line in the current window,
- press `<C-w>F` on the filename to edit the filename at the given line in a new window.

See `:help gF`, `:help ctrl-w_F`, and `:help 'switchbuf'`.

If you are doing something like `:terminal`, followed by `$ make`, then you are in the second case and the command (`bash` or whatever, here) is expected to keep "running" until stopped manually or by an error.

In this context, the command is "running" in `:terminal`, Vim stays in terminal-job mode and generally refuses to abandon the current terminal buffer. At this point, you should be able to:

1. go back to normal mode with `<C-w>N`,
2. press `<C-w>F` on the filename to edit the filename at the given line in a new window.

You can't use `gF`, here, because that would mean abandoning the current running shell, which Vim will refuse.

See `:help terminal-mode`.

But using the built-in quickfix feature is generally better anyway:

1. do `:make | cw`,
2. browse the list of errors,
3. open a given error at the given line AND column,
4. effortlessly go to next error,
5. etc.

`:help 30.1` is a great introduction to the feature. That is the first section of chapter 30 of the user manual, the 32 first chapters of which are required reading if you intend to use Vim for more than editing `/etc/hosts` from time to time.

Comment: Yeah, this almost worked, thanks. The only thing that is off is that the file:line is opened in a new buffer, but I already have that buffer open in vim, is there a workaround that?

Comment: Did you notice `:help 'switchbuf'`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I use `:make`, not `make` in a `:terminal`, but your wording to me suggested you do the latter.

---

You should clarify what you mean by "navigate".

Assuming that by *"run a `make` command within the vim's own terminal"* you mean roughly that you have done `:terminal` in your Vim session and that in *that* shell you've run `make`, you could just `vi main.c +23` in that very Vim terminal.

Beware that this will be a Vim session nested in the original!

Alternatively, you could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and then <kbd>:</kbd> to enter ex mode from the terminal window¹ and enter `e +23 main.c`.

This way the buffer will *replace* the terminal².

As regards

> I would like to go on the line above and from there

with short file names you're better off typing fast. But otherwise, move to that line the fastest way you can, then just `y`ank what you need (something like `0y2t:` once you are on that line, to copy `main.c:23`), then do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>-followed-by-<kbd>:</kbd> thing, and type `e` , then paste that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> followed by <kbd>"</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to see the magic of editing a command line with the full power of Vim. You'll need to change the `:` to `+` and bring `+23` to before the file name, maybe add a space, and finally hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

(¹) You normally do this in any window by just <kbd>:</kbd> from normal mode, but in the terminal you are typically in insert mode, and going normal mode would required you to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, and only then you could <kbd>:</kbd>; so you're faster the way I described.

(²) Well, not really, the buffer of the terminal will become hidden. And in the window it occupied your `main.c` will be shown.

Comment: I was after more like the behaviour in the `qf` window. You hit enter once your on the line with the error line, and you jump to that buffer and location.

Comment: Then you're using `:make`, not `make` in the Vim terminal? If that's the case, then why don't you do as you say in your comment?!